# Can $x^4 + y^4 = 1$ be parameterized in terms of $\theta $?

Tags: complex-analysis, parametrization

In general,  can equations of the form $(\frac {x}{a})^n + (\frac {y}{a})^n= 1 $ be parameterized in some polar form with $ r $ and $\theta $? (Where $ n $ is an even integer $> 2 $)

---

My assertion is that it cannot be parameterized.

Considering the equation in the title,  if we simply put $ y= mx $ (I.e line through origin making slope $ m $)(and, $ m= \tan {\theta} $) we can solve for $ x $ and $ y $ in terms of $\theta $. However you get a polynomial of degree 4. This means that $x$ (at some angle $\theta $) will have 4 values (two of which are complex). We are not able plot this in 2d.

Contrast this with a circle ($ x^2 + y^2=1 $). Varying $\theta $ always gives x and y values which are real. Because of which I can plot say only the y ordinate with respect to $\theta $ (which in other words is the sine function). Here you can get a function which we are able to plot in 2d.

Comment: Isn't
$$\left(\frac {x}{a}\right)^n + \left(\frac {y}{b}\right)^n= 1$$

Answer (score 1):

The same parametrization of ellipse can be adapted with its exponent manipulated:

$$ x = \cos ^ { 2/n} \theta \quad y = \sin ^ { 2/n} \theta $$

Comment: OP wanted them divided by $a$ and $b$, but the method works.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The $\theta$ we normally associate with an ellipse is not the angle made by line between the point on the ellipse and the origin, and the x-line. It is an angle formed with the circle enclosing the ellipse with the major/minor axis length as the radius. Hence we see that the parametric form of an ellipse is usually $(a \cos t, b \sin t)$

Comment: I believe it works. The general form looks like $(a^n\cos^{\frac{2}{n}}{\theta}, b^n\sin^{\frac{2}{n}}{\theta})$, but can we prove this geometrically?

Answer (score 0):

$x^4 + y^4 = 1$ can be parameterized as

$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
r_{12}(t)&=&(\pm\sqrt{\cos t},\; \sqrt{\sin(t)}),\; t \in [0,\pi/2]\\[0.2cm]
r_{34}(t)&=&(\sqrt{\cos t},\; \pm\sqrt{\sin(t)}),\; t \in [0,\pi/2]\\[0.2cm]
\end{array}\right.$

[image]